# How to change the underscores to letters in python hangman?

Tags: python

I am working on a hangmen project in python. However I do not know how to change the underlines to the letters inside the word if guessed properly. Here is my code:

```
import random
  
#pick word
with open("Words.txt", "r") as file:
   allText = file.read()
   words = list(map(str, allText.split()))
   word = random.choice(words)

#variables
guessed_letters = ""
guessed_words = ""
word_length = len(word)
completion = "_" * word_length
lives = 8


print(word)
print(completion)

guess = input("Please guess a letter or word.\n")
if
```

This is my file words.txt mentioned on line 4:
banana
nike
jordan
game
whole
hole
hi
hello

I tried to make letters show up In completion instead of it’s underline but I do not know how to. I am using a txt and I only found how to do it with a list or a dictionary.

Comment: You have to build a new string, since `str` values are immutable. I would suggest using a *list* of characters like `["_" for _ in range(word_length)]` to store the state of the game, and use `"".join(completion)` when you need a `str` to print.

Comment: Don't **replace** the underscores, rather regenerate the string every time a new letter is found without making those

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keeping a word of underscores and replace guessed letters in it, just regenerate the display word each round, generating by going over the answer word letter by letter, and for every letter that is in your guessed letters list, copy the correct letter and for letters that haven't been guessed, replace with underscore.  Generating this display word can be done in a one liner:

```
display_word = ''.join([(x if x in guesses else "_") for x in answer])
```

You can also use this displayed word as your win logic (all letters have been guessed, which is the same thing as saying there are no blank letters in the displayed word)

You can test for any unguessed letters in the displayed word with a simple:

```
winner = "_" not in display_word
```

Comment: ? I do not understand, sorry.

Comment: I added more verbose comments in my answer.